# Send message to client on connect via Spring Websocket

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket

Okay, I have practically read every single stackoveflow post on spring websocket. 
I want to send a message to a particular client once it connects to the server, simple!

I have been able to connect from the client, and I can listen for new connections on the server side. But when I try to send a message from the server side, nothing happens. Even though my client has subscribed.

Below is my client js.

```
var stompClient = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    connect();
});

function connect() {
var socket = new SockJS('/context_path/stockfeeds');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/share', function(message) {
        console.log("Subscription successful............");
        console.log(JSON.parse(message.body));
    });

    stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/reply', function(message) {
        console.log("Subscribed to user ...");
    });
}, function (error) {
    console.log("Stomp protocol error: "+ error);
});
}

$('#livetext').click(function () {
    stompClient.send('/app/stockfeeds', {}, 'This is BS');
});
```

The send send function works when I click '#livetext'. And a response is received on the client.
Below is my Controller.

```
@Controller
public class StockDispatchController {

    @Autowired
    LoggerService loggerService;

    @MessageMapping("/stockfeeds")
    @SendTo("/topic/share")
    public String fetchStocks(String message) throws Exception {
        loggerService.info("-----------------------------"+ message);

        return message;
    }

}
```

Below is my Connect event listener

```
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;

@Component
public class StompConnectEvent implements ApplicationListener<SessionConnectEvent> {

@Autowired
LoggerService logger;

@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

public void onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectEvent event) {

    this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/share", "A new client just connected");
    this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(event.getUser().getName(), "/queue/reply", "I just connected");
    logger.info("message template sent");
}

}
```

When a new client connects, the event listener is fired and runs to the end, but I don't get any response on the client.

Finally, below is my application context xml

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/stockfeeds">
        <websocket:handshake-interceptors>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor"/>
        </websocket:handshake-interceptors>
        <websocket:sockjs/>
    </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic, /queue"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a solution yet, but I found an alternative that works. So, instead of listening for SessionConnectedEvent, I added a controller method that gets fired when a user subscribes to it.

See below.

```
@SubscribeMapping("/reply")
public String initialReply() throws Exception {
    return "Welcome to the chat room.";
}
```

And I subscribe to it as below.

```
stompClient.subscribe('/app/reply', function(message) {
    alert(message.body);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite late here but just in case anyone might need this. Instead of using `SessionConnectEvent` which didn't work for me, I used `SessionSubscribeEvent` after reading the documentations and it worked.

```
@Component
public class StompConnectEvent implements ApplicationListener<SessionSubscribeEvent> {

@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

public void onApplicationEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {

    this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/share", messageObject);

    }
}
```

The `SessionSubscribeEvent` is called once the client subscribes to the websocket endpoint, so it can pick up messages sent to the endpoint by the server. But `SessionConnectEvent` is called when the client initially attempts to connect with the websocket, so the client isn't listening to the endpoint yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar use case and this is what i implemented successfully.

1. You can create some random string e.g `clientId23` at client side which you can send to server over established websocket.
2. Add same random string in subscribe URL e.g `/app/reply/clientId23`.
3. on server side, you can persist that clientId in db or something.. using which you can message that particular client e.g. `this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/app/reply/clientId23", "A new client just connected");`

Happy coding!